Add a docstring to a lua function in Roblox Studio
I want to create a docstring for a Lua function in Roblox Studios so that when i look at that function that i instantly know what this function does.
And currently the Popup looks like this:

But the Popup should look like this:

I tried with:
-- @param

-- Description

--// Description



and even with:
-- [[ ... ]]


I don't have Roblox Studio to test, but according to its documentation a block comment like this should be used to document functions
--[[
    Shuts off the cosmic moon ray immediately.

    Should only be called within 15 minutes of midnight Mountain Standard
    Time, or the cosmic moon ray may be damaged.
]]

Maybe -- [[ ... ]] does not work because it is a single line?

Roblox Studio does not support documentation comments so adding any comments to code won't be reflected in its popup.
Documentation comments for Roblox Studio has been requested for years now on the Roblox Developer Forum:

Custom Intellisense Documentation Comments
Add script editor support for Lua code documentation using comments (DocBlocks)

There have been developments for documentation comments, called user-defined function documentation, but as of now, it isn't publicly available and requires you to modify Roblox Studio to get it:

What do you guys think about User user defined function Documentation? A FFlag option

In order to get documentation comments there's nothing you can do now but wait for the official release of user-defined function documentation or to use a different IDE such as Visual Studio Code which does support code documentation using the syntax you are describing.
-- Given a string, turns it into a number
local function numberify(n: string): ()
    return tonumber(n)
end

For the above in Visual Studio Code, it shows the popup as:

Given a string, turns it into a number


This feature has been added to Studio!
Adding a comment above a function definition will add it to the intellisense as a docstring
example:
-- This adds 2 numbers together
local function add(a, b)
return a + b
end

